# Command to delete all files from folders matching name recursivly?

Tags: command-line, bash, rm

I have my base folder (let's call it base).

I have a bunch of folders inside, scattered at various depths within these folders are cache folders.

I want to delete all files from within the cache folders, but not the folders themselves.

I have tried

```
cd base
#then one of...
sudo rm -rf cache/*
sudo rm -rf *cache/*
sudo rm -rf cache*/*
sudo rm -rf *cache*/*
```

But really am just guessing, what would be the right command?

Comment: Someone downvoted this yet gave no comment?

Comment: It was probably downvoted because it's more to do with general scripting than do with Ubuntu. Should have been asked over at StackOverflow.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In bash, you can enable globstar and use `**` to match directories recursively

```
shopt -s globstar
echo rm -rf ./**/*cache*/*
```

See [Pattern Matching](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching)

Answer (score 3):

This will recursively delete all of the files within folders named `cache`, starting at the folder `base`. The `cache` folders themselves will still be intact, but all of the files within each will be removed.

```
find base -ipath "*/cache/*" -type f -delete
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the *extremely* powerful find command.

I would use something like this:

```
find . -iname *cache* -ok rm -rf {} \;
```

Now let me explain it for you. Find is the name of the application, it has a lot of options but for you, you won't need many of them.

The `.` means look in this current directory. This means you'll have to be in the right directory to start off with. I assume for you that is `~`

`-iname` means search my case insensitive name.

`*cache*` means that the name must contain cache.

Now the next part is important.

`-ok` means perform the commands that follow but as me if I want to do it first. This can be replaced with `-exec` but I wouldn't advise it. That would delete things without telling you and you don't want that.

Ok, so the next line (which is the stuff that `-ok` runs) is `rm -rf {} \;`

The `rm -rf` I hope is self explanatory. The `{}` is basically a placeholder for the name of the file it has found. The `\;` at the end just means it is the end of that line.

I hope that makes sense.

I advise running the find command without everything right of and including `-ok`. It will pump out a list of all the cache files first and you can review them. Then add the `-ok` section and get cracking!

Comment: You forgot to quote the pattern for `-iname`; that'll lead to errors if there happens to be files matching that pattern in the current directory. Also, this approach deletes the cache directories as well, not just the contents.

Comment: This will delete all folders named cache including the files in them. OP wants to delete files in folders named cache, not the folders themselves

Answer (score 1):

Just replace basedir by the path of the base directory you want to remove

```
$ find basedir -type f -delete
```

If you feel more confortable moving previously to your base dir, then:

```
$ cd basedir
$ find . -type f -delete
```